# Creating a function at checkbox click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-7, bootstrap-vue

Here I need to write a function to display "is the spa" section when the user clicks the "Spa" checkbox.This is a laravel/Vue js project.

---

This is the bootstrap-vue code I wrote for checkboxes

```
 <template>
    <b-form-group label="Construction is a: ">
            <b-form-checkbox-group
            v-model="selected"
            :options="options"
            name="flavour-2a"
            stacked
            ></b-form-checkbox-group>
    </b-form-group>
</template>



<script>
    selected: [], // Must be an array reference!
    options: [
      { text: 'Pool', value: 'pool' },
      { text: 'Spa', value: 'spa' },
      { text: 'Pool & Spa', value: 'poolAndSpa'},         
      
      ],
</script>
// **This is the function I wrote** ,
 <b-form-group label="Construction is a: ">
            <b-form-radio-group
            v-model="selected"
            :options="options"
            name="poolConstruction"
            @change="radioChange($event)"
            stacked
            ></b-form-radio-group>
        </b-form-group> 

       radioChange: function(e) {
        if(this.selected == "spa"||"poolAndSpa"){
            
            document.getElementById("spaRadio").style.display = "block";
        }else
                        
        {
        document.getElementById("spaRadio").style.display = "none";
        }
```

Comment: I need to write a function on "Spa" checkbox . So then, user can see another two radio buttons when he clicked "spa"

Comment: add a change event on the checkbox and conditionally render the data to check if its spa, if yes show the radio buttons else dont.

Comment: @MrKhan I updated the question. I tried the way you told me as I understood. I'm new to this. What was possibly went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's clear out what you need.

1. When ever the checkbox is clicked, you want to run a method
2. In the method, you will check the value of the clicked checkbox.
3. If the value of the checkbox is 'spa', then display the radio button else hide them

HTML code:
A rough structure, you can populate your radio button code in the div with `spaRadio` Id. We have added `@change` method on the check boxes and the rest is the same.

```
<div id="app">
  <b-container>
    <b-row>    
     <b-form-group class="mx-auto">
        <b-form-checkbox-group buttons @change="handleChange($event)"  name="butons1" class="customCheck1" :options="chartOptions" v-customcheckbox="chartOptions">
        </b-form-checkbox-group>
      </b-form-group>      
    </b-row>
    <b-row>
       <p class="mx-auto">  Selcted:  {{ charts }}</p>
    </b-row> 
    <div id="spaRadio" class="hide">
        <p>Radio's here<p>
    </div>
  </b-container>
</div>
```

Next, in the method, we will add a condition to check if its equal to 'spa' or 'poolAndSpa'. To check the condition we will match selected value with each expected filter. This is a wrong of comparing.

```
this.selected == "spa"||"poolAndSpa"
```

The right way:

```
 (this.selected == "spa" || this.selected == "poolAndSpa")
```

**Method:**

```
  methods: {
    handleChange: function(e) {
        const name = e;
        this.selected = name; //====> assign selected value
        let result = this.selected.find(el=> (el=== "spa") || (el=== "poolAndSpa")); //====> this will search for the filter keywords 'spa' or 'poolAndSpa'
        if(result !== undefined){ //====> if any one of them is found then this will return a value else it will be undefind
          document.getElementById("spaRadio").style.display = "block"; //===> display radio
        }else {
          document.getElementById("spaRadio").style.display = "none"; //===> hide
        } 
    }
  },
```

**Working example:**
https://codepen.io/AhmedKhan1/pen/LYNQNmw

Comment: @dharman That worked! thanks. And I found another way to show hide the related element. 
    `<div v-show ="selected == 'spa' || selected ==  'poolAndSpa'"> `                                      
 This also worked .

Comment: Great brother! i just provided you with a simple relevant example. how you improve it is in your hands. Keep it up!